# Dropdown menus in PysimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, drop-down-menu, pysimplegui

I am looking for a PysimpleGUI way to create dropdown menus.
Currently, I can create ComboBoxes as such:

```
import PySimpleGui as sg
sg.Combo(list1, size = params)
```

This creates an Input box and a dropdown list with a slider populated by list1 elements.

---

However, my users are very sloppy with inputs and I'd like to restrict them to a simple dropdown list.

---

Now I know I could maybe use the ListBox element but it doesn't have a slider/seems much less versatile than Combo.

---

What other arguments could I pass to Combo to make this work?

---

NB:In the documentation they state that Combo == InputCombo == Drop == DropDown but without giving more details but it confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no slider when ListBox is has not enough entries however one appears when enough are added.

`sg.Listbox(list(df_names.NAMES), size=(20,4), enable_events=False, key='_LIST_')`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `readonly` to True

`sg.Combo(..., readonly=True)`